# CSS/JS cursor on java applet

Tags: javascript, css, applet, cursor

I'm working on a website that uses a java applet to create a "virtual tour" of a room for a restaurant. It takes a large panoramic image, a loading image, and the applet's .jar file and creates the applet. The applet was already created in use for their old site, so I just get to redeploy it.

I want to use a move cursor on it instead of the default cursor, but I can't seem to affect it with either JavasSript or CSS styling. I've tried inline on the applet tag, in the style sheet, and even in the jQuery that loads it.

Not sure how useful the code would be to this question, but just in case relevant snippets of code below:

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $(".tourlink a").click(function(e) {
        $(".instructions").remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href"),
            $target = $("#virtual"),
            targetOffset = $target.offset().top,
            distance = Math.abs($(this).offset().top - targetOffset);
        $target.load(url+" #app", function() {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000 + (distance / 5));
        }).before('<p class="center instructions"><strong>Click and drag your mouse to tour the area</strong></p>');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<h1>Virtual Tour</h1>
    <div style="width:300px; float:right;">
    <h2>Evansville</h2>
    <ul class="tourlink">
        <li><a href="tour/tour.asp?tour=entrance" target="_blank">Entrance</a></li>
        <li><a href="tour/tour.asp?tour=large" target="_blank">Large Hibachi</a></li>
        <li><a href="tour/tour.asp?tour=small" target="_blank">Small Hibachi</a></li>
        <li><a href="tour/tour.asp?tour=sushi" target="_blank">Sushi Bar &amp; Dining Area</a></li>
        <li><a href="tour/tour.asp?tour=banquet" target="_blank">Private Dining</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="width:300px; float:left;">
    <h2>Lexington</h2>
    <ul class="tourlink">
        <li><a href="tour/tour.asp?tour=lexbar" target="_blank">Bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="tour/tour.asp?tour=lexsushi" target="_blank">Sushi Bar</a></li>
        <li><a href="tour/tour.asp?tour=lexhibachi1" target="_blank">Hibachi 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="tour/tour.asp?tour=lexhibachi2" target="_blank">Hibachi 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

APPLET (the file param changes depending on the link)

```
<div id="app">
    <applet archive="/review/nagasaki-inn/tour/ptviewer.jar" code="ptviewer.class" width="700" height="480">
        <param name="file" value="/review/nagasaki-inn/tour/large.jpg" />
        <param name="wait" value="/review/nagasaki-inn/tour/naglogo.jpg" />
    </applet>
</div><!--app-->
```

Comment: It's a good chance that it's not possible. It probably has to be done inside the applet.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with an applet before, specifically using processing and I could change the cursor only inside the app with code like:

```
cursor(MOVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [setCursor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setCursor%28java.awt.Cursor%29) on the component within the Java applet source code.

```
setCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR);
```

Do you have access to the Java source and can you recompile it? If you don't have access to the source it may be possible for you to decompile the Applet class and recompile but beware if this is third party code this may be against the license.